# ASP - TextBox accept only characters [UniCode] - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, unicode

I have a **TextBox** where introduce Text(Three names). I want this textbox accept only characters in UNICODE format!

**This is my (wrong)code for ASCII format:**

```
           if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtThreeNames.Text, "[a-zA-Z]^"))
            {
                return "Three names, must be a string !";
            }
```

Comment: You could utilize `char.IsLetter` method for checking each character, it also supports unicode. Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The Text property of a TextBox control is typed String. Therefore, its contents is Unicode characters. The TextBox accepts whatever characters you type or paste into it, perhaps with the exception of stripping or translating newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static bool IsASCII(this string value)
{
    // ASCII encoding replaces non-ascii with question marks, so we use UTF8 to see if multi-byte sequences are there
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(value) == value.Length;
}
```

source: http://snipplr.com/view/35806/